# Express not sending or not reaching route

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, morgan

I have a pretty large file base so It is hard to show everything.

I have an express server with some routes, one being POST /set route. Almost every time I try and post something to the server I get no response at all, In fact, The first thing I do in /set is to log a simple hello and it does not appear to even reach the route. I am using the Morgan logger to log requests and this is what it shows:
[image: Notice the first few request come through]

The first few request go through but not that specific route. as well as other routes work afterward. This happens constantly on this route, but will occasionally happen on other routes and I get an "ERRCONRESET" error whenever this happens. When this happens, if I send the request right away within a few seconds of the first failing it will go through.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

There is a lack of code because it is not reaching the route, it might be dropping the connected because of a middleware or something in express but there is no errors being logged. For middlewares I am using "bodyParser", "session", "cookieParser", "helmet", "morgan" "gzip" and "passport". There is also no authentication middle applied to this route.

Comment: I understand you have a large file base, but there's not I can suggest based on 2 lines of code. Can you provide the entire route code? Also, the first few requests go through? Can you give an example of the code that represents the successful execution?

Comment: Well, I only showed the route to show that I am logging hello. The app doesn't even get this far. It does not log hello, so there is something going on before this route is even being called on expresses end, maybe a middleware could cause this. For middlewares I have "bodyParser", "session", "cookieParser", "helmet", "gzip" and "passport"

Comment: Got it. More to the point that if you suspect the issue resides in a particular area of code, you should post that. Otherwise we'd all be spitballing, which won't help anyone fast.

Comment: I know it is not that useful, but that is actually what I am looking for. I have no idea where or why this is happening. I am hoping that someone else has had a similar issue and can explain what they did to resolve. I Think If I wanted anything but a guess in the dark I would have to upload all my code, which is not possible so I am willing to take any suggestions.

Comment: Out of the middleware you have listed, the only times I have had similar issues was with bodyParser. Whether encoding or type json etc, but impossible to give more advice without seeing code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think express doesn't end you request because you never send anything; so the request time out.

Try to send a simple string instead of doing nothing:

```
  app.post('/set', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
  });
```

Comment: It does send a response just, later on. If the route was called, it would first log "hello" to the output then yes would timeout (if it never returns response), but it is never reaching the log which is the first line in the route.

Comment: I reproduce the time out when I doesn't send a response, but the log 'hello' is well displayed. So the issue must come from another part of your code, or from a middleware... Check if you don't have another route '/set' in your application, or try to post the minimal code to reproduce the issue...

Comment: Are you sure that your console.log() are written in your Morgan log file?

Comment: There is no log file, it sends all to stdout.